# Backup postgresql database inside docker

Tags: docker, pg-dump

I'm trying to create a backup of a database with pg_dump.

This is the script I'm using:

```
docker exec container -u postgres pg_dump db > backup.sql
```

But the dump is way smaller than the original database.

The original db is over 800mb, the dump about 300mb.